# How to delete an element from a HashMap?

Tags: rust

I am learning to build a simple CRUD system in Rust, but not sure how to remove an item from the list. Mapping through the list and then when it is matching the item in the todo `HashMap`, it should delete it from this list.

```rust
if action == "remove" {
    match todo.remove(&item) {
        None => println!("'{}' is not present in the list", item),
        Some(_) => match todo.save() {
            Ok(_) => println!("todo saved"),
            Err(why) => println!("An error occurred: {}", why),
        },
    }
}
    
fn remove(&mut self, key: &String) -> Option<()> {
    match self.map.get_mut(key) {
        Some(v) => Some(v),
        None => None,
    }
}
```

Could someone tell me how I can do that in Rust?

Comment: `get_mut` gives you a mutable reference to an element of the hashmap so that you can modify is value. You want [`remove`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.remove). By the way, if your values are `()`, then a `HashSet` might be more appropriate. (Likewise, making the `action` an enum instead of a string would also be more appropriate.) I do not understand though why you would delete an item and then immediately save (=insert?) it again.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace `self.map.get_mut(key)` with `self.map.remove(key)`

- **get_mut**: Returns a mutable reference of value related to the exisitng key. `Option<&mut V>`
- **remove**:  deletes the key/value pair and returns the value if key exists. `Option<V>`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of getting a mutable reference to the value in the `HashMap`, to remove the item you should probably be using the [`remove`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.remove) method, which returns an `Option` possibly containing the value that was removed. Assuming that your `HashMap` is a `HashMap<String, Todo>`, your `remove` method could look like this:

```
fn remove(&mut self, key: &String) -> Option<Todo> {
    self.map.remove(key)
}
```

That being said, a [`HashSet`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html) or other collection could be a better fit for your use case. I would also imagine that you don't want to be saving a todo directly removing it, so your top code block could look like this if you also changed your action to an enum:

```
match action {
    ...
    Action::Remove(item) => {
        match todo.remove(&item) {
            Some(value) => println!("{:?} removed from list", value),
            None => println!("'{}' is not present in the list", item),
        };
    },
    ...
}
```